# How to get Selected items in WPF CheckBox ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, checkbox

Am Using the checkbox in listbox items, how to get the selected checkboxes from the list

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,68,0,12" Name="listBox1" Width="156" IsEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Focusable="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" FontSize="12" Padding="5" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                      
                               <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=CNames}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I tried to loop thru the selected items in the listboxitems, but it throws exception in listboxitem

```
 private void btnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListBoxItem item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == "true")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Content.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception and from what line is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 5):

You could move the data context for each of these items away from the UI and create an ObservableCollection of objects

```
public ObservableCollection<CheckedItem> List { get;set;}

public class CheckedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool selected;
  private string description;

  public bool Selected 
  { 
     get { return selected; }
     set 
     {
        selected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
     }
  }

  public string Description 
  { 
     get { return description; }
     set
     {
         description = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Description");
     }
   }

  /* INotifyPropertyChanged implementation */
}
```

Then in your ListBox ItemTemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}" 
              Content={Binding Path=Description}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Your selected items are now available in the ObservableCollection rather than looping through UI elements

Comment: This is how I have implemented the same in the past +1.  One minor point: you may want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `CheckedItem` in case two way binding is needed.

Comment: Agreed on INotifyPropertyChanged. It does really depend on your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Have your template like this

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate> 
 ........
   <CheckBox Content="" 
      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"  />
 ..........
    <!-- Use Other UIElements to Show your Data -->
```

then the above binding will sync two way with your models isSelected and list view selection, then in code use SelectedItems.

```
For Each s As myPoco In myListView1.SelectedItems
   ' do something here with
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this code:

```
 private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (CheckBox item in list1.Items)
     {
         if (item.IsChecked)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(item.Content.ToString());
         }
     }
 }
```