# How to retrieve a list of all checked items in the listbox ? Silverlight WP7.1

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

This is my listbox, how can I retrieve the items that has been checked, in code-behind ?

```
    <ListBox Name="AppointmentResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attendees}" Height="400"  ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control" Margin="24,0,0,0" >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                      </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
<Button Content="Skicka" Click="SendPhoto_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if that solves your problem:

[How to get Selected items in WPF CheckBox ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039376/how-to-get-selected-items-in-wpf-checkbox-listbox)

View model approach is usually recommended.

Comment: Actually, this is the only proper solution to do it ;-)

Comment: remember to mark the answer if you found it helpful ask ask for further support if not

Answer (score 0):

The listbox is IEnumerable.  I haven't actually compiled this, but something like:

```
var checked = AppointmentResultsData.ItemsSource.Where(i => i.IsChecked);
```