# Select a CheckBox in a ListBox by clicking on the background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a little problem with my `ListBox`
I can check a `CheckBox` by clicking on the text,
But if I click on the background I can't check my `CheckBox`
That make me feel so bad...

I suppose that I can create a method to solve my problem,
But I would like to know if there a property to fix this easily.
Thanks for helping.

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeleteEntreesListBox">
    <CheckBox x:Name="myTextBox" Content="Hello"/>
</ListBox>
```

If my cursor is on the text the box is gray and can be check.
[Screen](http://puu.sh/ffodT/6421bea219.png)
If my cursor is not on the text but on the background the box is white and can't be check [Screen](http://puu.sh/ffofD/7d2b57715d.png)

EDIT : It seems that there are no property to fix that.
So how could I do to handle that with for example a `OnMouseLeftButtonDown`.
The item selected by the left button must set the box as check..

Comment: Are you talking about when you listbox item changes? There should be an event for it SelectedIndexChanged. You can on that event cast the selected item as a checkbox and then put checked = true. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: When your cursor is ON the ListBox.Item (background blue : selected) I want to be able to click anywhere in this blue area to check  my box. Actually, I must click ON the text to do that..

Comment: So clicking that 'blue background' should change the listbox selected item. Have you tried [that event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Just bind ischecked of the checkbox to isselected of the item

Comment: @MethodMan : I am working on ListBox, not ListView

Comment: @alykins : That event is not what I want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039376/how-to-get-selected-items-in-wpf-checkbox-listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the width same as the list box (or any other parent)

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeleteEntreesListBox">
    <CheckBox x:Name="myTextBox" Content="Hello" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=DeleteEntreesListBox}"/>
</ListBox>
```

*EDIT

You can bind `IsChecked` to the `IsSelected` Property of the ancestor ListBoxItem.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myTextBox2" Content="Hello" 
          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
          AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
          Path=IsSelected}"/>
```

Or you can use `IValueConverter` with more flexibility and pass in an identifier like the `SelectedIndex` of the list + a `ConverterParameter` with a matching `int` and convert to `true` if they match (or any other identifier).

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeleteEntreesListBox">
    <CheckBox x:Name="myTextBox1" Content="Hello">
        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
            <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" ElementName="DeleteEntreesListBox" Converter="{StaticResource IndexToBoolConverter}">
                <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                    <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                </Binding.ConverterParameter>
            </Binding>
        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
    </CheckBox>
</ListBox>
```

Notice that you'll need to reference this in your xaml in order to pass an int as a parameter:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and the converter can be something like this:

```
class IndexToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            if (parameter != null && (int)value == (int)parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

though I think you should create a nice `UserControl` of your own that inherits from `ListBox` and modify it as you wish.

Comment: Nice try but I need to keep this width.